# How to make select every iteration Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, select

I have table names with name and surname columns. I want to grab random name and surname from it, i tried this, but it takes one name and surname and prints it 100 times so it makes only one select at the start and then uses it's value,how can i fix it?

```
SELECT (SELECT name FROM names WHERE ID = ROUND(RANDOM() * 10 + 1)),
       (SELECT surname FROM names WHERE ID = ROUND(RANDOM() * 10 + 1))
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 100);
```

Comment: what is the min and max value of the id from names table ?

Comment: 1 and 19 but numbers here just for an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for Postgres to evaluate the select in the subquery multiple times, it needs to look like a *correlated subquery* -- one whose results depend on the values being returned by the top-level query. A minor problem here is that you don't actually care about those values. You can hack around that by meaninglessly including them in the subqueries, like this:

```sql
SELECT (SELECT name FROM names WHERE ID = ROUND(RANDOM() * 10 + 1 + i - i)),
       (SELECT surname FROM names WHERE ID = ROUND(RANDOM() * 10 + 1 + i - i))
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 100) i;
```

Another approach would be to move the subqueries to your FROM clause, put a different generate_series clause in each one, and then join them on the output of each series, but that ends up being really complicated SQL.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't use the generateseries in the subquery , try with this

```
SELECT (SELECT name FROM names WHERE ID = ROUND(RANDOM() * 10 + g)),
       (SELECT surname FROM names WHERE ID = ROUND(RANDOM() * 10 + g))
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 100) g;
```